# postgresql trigger unexpected behaviour by many copies of inserted row

Tags: postgresql, trigger

On insert in tbl1, the trigger I am working on, copies rows in tbl2 with some updates.

Trigger:

```
create or replace function myprocedure() returns trigger as
begin 
IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT')THEN 
 insert into tbl2
 select new.* from tbl1 ;

 update tbl2
 set (field1, field2) =  ...
 where gid = new.gid;

 return new ;
 END IF ;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS mytrig ON public.tbl1 ;
CREATE TRIGGER mytrig AFTER INSERT or UPDATE on public.tbl1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE myprocedure();
```

My problem is:

- The first insert in tbl1 gives 1 insert in tbl2. It is fine.
- The second insert in tbl1 gives 2 (identical) lines in tbl2 (values of second insert)
- The third insert in tbl1 gives 3 (identical) lines in tbl2 (values of third insert)
- etc.

I am feeling a little lost. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you do an update on `tbl2`? Anyway you must add a where clause with the primary key of the `new` row to the update. You are now updating all rows in `tbl2`.

Also the insert is inserting `new.*` for every row already in `tbl1`.

Why don't you rewrite the insert into something:

```
insert into tbl2 (field1, field2, ...) values (new.field1, new.field2, ...);
```

Now you can set the correct values and do not need an update afterwards.

Comment: update is needed to normalize datas. (I tested it and doesn't seem to be the problem). I updated the code too.

Comment: Think you forgot to remove a `;` in the update. Changed my reply too.

Comment: Values instead of Insert works fine. There is just **one line** in tbl2 for **one** line inserted in tbl1. (One more thing I do not understand...). Thanks anyway/

Comment: @Leehan the main problem was the `from tbl1` because it was inserting a row (of the whole table `tbl1`) for **each and every row** of the INSERT. You could even replace the `select new.* from u` with `select new.* ;`